# Remote access from my PC to MySQL 5.6 installed on VPS with Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, vps

I have just bought VPS and installed mysql-server-5.6 on it. I will be deploying app which uses this database but for now I would like to connect to the database I created from my PC or laptop using, for example, Navicat.

How can I do that? I know its called remote access and found examples like this one: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html
but the problem is, that my computer/laptop often changes IP address, so I cant grant access using particular IP address.

Is it possible to grant access to full database/or single table, but not to particular IP?

Lets assume I would create in MySQL some user with login and password. And then, when logging from Navicat I would have to pass these login/password to connect to db?

I hope you see what I mean. Thanks for you answers!

Comment: accessing it via ssh might be a better solution for you.

Comment: @castis I use PuTTy on windows and ssh on terminal on my macbook, but this way I connect to my server and then can connect to mysql. I need graphical presentation of my databases like on Navicat or Workbench; edit: and, I would like to use database from VPS in my localhost-application

Comment: @RonThompson the problem is that my router at home changes IP often, its not static. Thus I cannot grant access as the page I linked in the question said, to single IP address. 
Nope, I owe VPS for 2 days and server stays in France. There is an ubuntu system with mysql installed and I want to connect from my computer at home, to mysql on my VPS - in a shortcut

Comment: i already have IP address of my vps and DNS as well. Now I need to connect to installed mysql which runs on the server. how?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Requirements:

You have a rented server with MySQL installed, located elsewhere. 
You have 1+ computers located inside your local network that need to connect to a basic database also inside your network, until you deploy to the server.

Once you go to the server, you can use the IP address given for it (if it is statically assigned) or use the host-provided DNS fully qualified domain name for it to resolve to a dynamically assigned IP.

For now, you can STATICALLY assign your Private IP address for the computer the database resides on in your network. Log in to your router, find the static section, assign a private IP (typically 192.x.x.small number) that's NOT currently in use on your local network. Reboot the machine and run IPconfig/Ifconfig and verify that it has this statically assigned IP address.

NOTE: this address will only be useable by other machines on the same network. To go OUTSIDE your local network and connect BACK into your local network, you must purchase DNS from someone and port forward from your router to the proper machine.

Now use this IP address in your login/connection request.